# Fabric js Text characters garbled on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad, fabricjs

We are using Fabric js to insert text in canvas, there are 2 texts which we are inserting, one is a larger text which loads correctly and has Open Sans font. Another is a smaller text which is where we are having problem, it has dynamic fonts loaded from google fonts library dynamically. Instead of displaying the characters it displays questions marks in the boxes. We tried using Open Sans font but there is no change.

For Further explanation you can check the following link 
 I have used following code which is creating problem

```
_preloadText: function(index,value)
        {
            var fontSize = value.default;
            var coords = this._getXYCoordinates(value.coordinates);
            var fontFamily = this.options.fontFamily;
            var options = $.extend({
                            fontFamily: fontFamily,
                            fontSize: fontSize,
                            useNative:true
                        },this._getOptions(coords.x,coords.y));
            if('text' == value.type)
            {
                options.fontStyle = 'bold';
                options.fontFamily = 'Open Sans';
                var title = new fabric.Text(value.text,options);
                this.canvasLayer2.add(title);
                this.canvasLayer2.centerObjectH(title);
                this.canvasLayer2.setActiveObject(title);
                this.canvasLayer2.renderAll();
            }else{
                /*The below code is where the problem of fallback font is.*/
                var slogan = new fabric.Text(value.text,options);
                this.canvasLayer3.add(slogan);
                this.canvasLayer3.centerObjectH(slogan);
                this.canvasLayer3.setActiveObject(slogan);
                this.canvasLayer3.renderAll();
            }           
        }
```

There are others who have also faced this issue. You can check by opening the following codepen in iPhone or iPad
https://codepen.io/kelvin-im/pen/xrRNEx/

I also found this issue listed in the fabric js github account
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/4009

But the developer abruptly closed the issue without paying any hid to the comments.

**Edit**

Here is the font loading code which is called first when this jquery widget is initialized.

```
_prepareFont: function(){
            var that = this;
            if(this.options.fontFamily !== null){
                require(['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js'],function(WebFont){
                    WebFont.load({
                        google: {
                            families: [that.options.fontFamily]
                        },
                        active: function() {
                            that._prepareCanvas();
                            that._prepareControls();                            
                        },
                        fontactive: function(familyName, fvd){
                            that.options.fontFamily = familyName;
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```

In the WebFont library we are loading the font and on active event, we are calling the _prepareControls Method, which pre-loads the text to canvas. In case we don't get the desired font from the google WebFont Library, we are using Open Sans font, which is already added in the page.

We are using 2 instances of fabric.Text class, one is loading, The other is not.

Answer (score 2):

The abrupt developer, me, asked twice to see the font loading code.
The fonts must be loaded by the browser before trying to use them on canvas.

Otherwise you get a fallback font or garbage on screen.

Now i moved the codepen here, i wrapped headline in a 2 seconds timeout.
You will notice that on iphone/ipad or other slow devices, those 2 seconds should be enough for the google server to feed you first the css string, and then a second request the browser needs to get the font file and for the canvas to load it, while the other text could come out as garbage the Headeline should not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.browser-type').html(bowser.name + ' ' + bowser.version);    
  
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  
    $('.fabric-type').html(fabric.version);
  
    var headline = new fabric.IText('Headline', {
      "originX": "center",
      "originY": "center",
      "left": 512,
      "top": 117,
      "width": 83.6,
      "height": 56.5,
      "fill": "#ffffff",
      "stroke": null,
      "strokeWidth": 0,
      "strokeDashArray": null,
      "strokeLineCap": "butt",
      "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
      "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
      "scaleX": 0.8,
      "scaleY": 1,
      "angle": 0,
      "flipX": false,
      "flipY": false,
      "opacity": 1,
      "shadow": "",      
      "visible": true,
      "clipTo": null,
      "backgroundColor": "",
      "fillRule": "nonzero",
      "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
      "transformMatrix": null,
      "skewX": 0,
      "skewY": 0,
      "name": "Headline txt",
      "locked": ["stroke"],
      "perPixelTargetFind": false,
      "fontSize": 165,
      "fontWeight": "800",
      "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
      "fontStyle": "italic",
      "lineHeight": 1.16,
      "textDecoration": "",
      "textAlign": "center",
      "textBackgroundColor": "",
      "styles": {
        "0": {
          "1": {},
          "2": {},
          "3": {},
          "4": {},
          "5": {},
          "6": {},
          "7": {}
        }
      }
    });
  
    var dateTime = new fabric.IText('Date | Time', {
      "originX": "center",
      "originY": "center",
      "left": 512,
      "top": 206,
      "width": 170.31,
      "height": 31.64,
      "fill": "#ffffff",
      "stroke": null,
      "strokeWidth": 0,
      "strokeDashArray": null,
      "strokeLineCap": "butt",
      "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
      "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
      "scaleX": 0.9,
      "scaleY": 1,
      "angle": 0,
      "flipX": false,
      "flipY": false,
      "opacity": 1,
      "shadow": "",
      "visible": true,
      "clipTo": null,
      "backgroundColor": "",
      "fillRule": "nonzero",
      "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
      "transformMatrix": null,
      "skewX": 0,
      "skewY": 0,
      "name": "date/time",
      "locked": ["stroke"],
      "perPixelTargetFind": false,
      "fontSize": 28,
      "fontWeight": "400",
      "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
      "fontStyle": "italic",
      "lineHeight": 1.16,
      "textDecoration": "",
      "textAlign": "center",
      "textBackgroundColor": "",
      "styles": {
        "0": {
          "1": {},
          "2": {},
          "3": {},
          "4": {}
        }
      }
    });
  
    var vsText = new fabric.IText('vs.', {
      "originX": "center",
      "originY": "center",
      "left": 512,
      "top": 255,
      "width": 83.6,
      "height": 56.5,
      "fill": "#ffffff",
      "stroke": null,
      "strokeWidth": 0,
      "strokeDashArray": null,
      "strokeLineCap": "butt",
      "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
      "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
      "scaleX": 0.8,
      "scaleY": 1,
      "angle": 0,
      "flipX": false,
      "flipY": false,
      "opacity": 1,
      "shadow": "",
      "visible": true,
      "clipTo": null,
      "backgroundColor": "",
      "fillRule": "nonzero",
      "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
      "transformMatrix": null,
      "skewX": 0,
      "skewY": 0,
      "name": "versus txt",
      "locked": ["stroke"],
      "perPixelTargetFind": false,
      "fontSize": 50,
      "fontWeight": "400",
      "fontFamily": "RIVERHACK",
      "fontStyle": "",
      "lineHeight": 1.16,
      "textDecoration": "",
      "textAlign": "left",
      "textBackgroundColor": "",
      "styles": {
        "0": {
          "1": {},
          "2": {},
          "3": {}
        }
      }
    });
  
    var sideText = new fabric.IText('SIDEBAR', {
      "originX": "center",
      "originY": "center",
      "left": 50,
      "top": 30,
      "width": 90.72,
      "height": 36.21,
      "fill": "#0c0c0c",
      "stroke": null,
      "strokeWidth": 0,
      "strokeDashArray": null,
      "strokeLineCap": "butt",
      "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
      "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
      "scaleX": 1,
      "scaleY": 1,
      "angle": 0,
      "flipX": false,
      "flipY": false,
      "opacity": 1,
      "shadow": "",
      "visible": true,
      "clipTo": null,
      "backgroundColor": "",
      "fillRule": "nonzero",
      "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
      "transformMatrix": null,
      "skewX": 0,
      "skewY": 0,
      "name": "sidebar txt",
      "locked": ["stroke"],
      "perPixelTargetFind": false,
      "fontSize": 18,
      "fontWeight": "400",
      "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
      "fontStyle": "",
      "lineHeight": 0.78,
      "textDecoration": "",
      "textAlign": "center",
      "textBackgroundColor": "",
      "styles": {
        "0": {
          "1": {},
          "2": {},
          "3": {},
          "4": {},
          "5": {},
          "6": {},
          "7": {},
          "8": {}
        },
        "1": {
          "0": {},
          "1": {},
          "2": {},
          "3": {},
          "4": {}
        }
      }
    });
    
    canvas.add(sideText);
    canvas.add(dateTime);
    canvas.add(vsText);
    setTimeout(function() {
        canvas.add(headline);
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
@import 
url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i);

#c {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #aaa;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #999;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bowser/1.0.0/bowser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.13/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <b>Browser:</b> <span class="browser-type"></span><br>
  <b>Fabric JS:</b> <span class="fabric-type"></span>
  <br><br>
  
  <div>
    <canvas id='c' width="1024" height="1024"></canvas>
  </div>  
</div>
```

In safari:

[image]

Comment: Let me edit and update the font loading code here in the question, I am initializing the canvas after the font is loaded from google webfont js.

Comment: can you see the fond from this snippet on an iphone?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can not run snippet on iPhone in SO.

Comment: I have created a pen using your code here is the url for the same: https://codepen.io/taralpatoliya/pen/PjxMZW and it is showing garbled characters for the smaller texts.

Comment: so that confirms that your app needs more time to load fonts. because the extra time is applied just on the big headline text. use a better fontloader. try webFontloader is small and crossbrowser and easy to integrate

Comment: I am using the WebFontLoader already, you can check the code snippet i added in the edit.
https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader